# Unexpected CDialog DoModal() behavior

Tags: windows, mfc

I am debugging a strange issue with a 3rd party library that displays a formatted message box.  The library uses a class based on CDialog and runs the message box dialog with the DoModal() method.  Sometimes a message is displayed from a common subroutine that uses the handle of the main window as the parent (type 1), other times from another modal dialog (type 2).

Sometimes a Type 1 call is triggered by an action in a modal dialog and when this happens, the original dialog is no longer modal after the message dialog is dismissed.  Changing nothing except the formatted message box with the system default message box and the original dialog stays modal, as expected.
When a Type 2 call is made, the original dialog always remains modal, so I am working to ensure that is how I call the library function, but this looks like it might be a bug in the CDialog itself, so I thought I would ask if anyone knows about this.

I have never worked with these class libraries before (I'm an old school C guy), but it looks like the library is always using EndDialog() to terminate the modal message box and there's no "fancy, low-level" windows stuff that I can find (other than the message formatting).  It is probably obvious that I don't really know what I'm asking, so if there is a better place to discuss this, please send me there.

On the other hand, if anything derived from CDialog and DoModal() does this, it would appear to be a bug in the class library, since built-in modal dialogs (like MessageBox) do not have this unwanted effect.  I would share the library code, but I am not the original author and I don't have permission, but I am willing to look for things as long as you are willing to have some patience for someone not familiar with C++ code structuring.

Comment: Are you sure it is a `CDialog` class, not `CDialogEx`? The latter has some issues. Also it's difficult to follow your question without any source code.

Comment: The class stars with `class MessageBoxEx : public CDialog` so, as I understand it, the class is based on `CDialog`, right?  Sorry about code, I have no idea what specific snippets to post and I don't own it, so I cannot simply share large blocks.

Comment: Are all dialogs owned by the same thread? And yes, `EndDialog` *is* the low-level Windows API call to close a modal dialog.

Comment: @iinspectable I know `EndDialog` is correct, but I don't know what _additional_ things the `CDialog` class might be doing behind the scenes.  Apparently, it is different from what `MessageBox` (or any "standard" modal dialog) does.  I worked around the problem by finding a way for the shared functions that pop messages to always use the active modal window handle or main window handle, as appropriate, but I should not need to do that.  Oh well, I don't think there will ever be an answer to this.  Thanks to all for considering it, though.

Comment: I'm not immediately aware of anything that MFC does internally, that would exhibit the behavior you observe. Make sure you have a look at [CDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdialog-class?view=vs-2019#cdialog)'s c'tor: The `pParentWnd` parameters have default values. If you don't pass a parent (which is really an *owner*), MFC will go looking for an appropriate owner window. It would certainly help to see a [mcve] to provide directed help.

Comment: Regardless, the important question I asked previously is still unanswered: Are you establishing a window hierarchy across threads? In case you do, all sorts of wrong can happen.

Comment: As for the parent `HWND`, my low-level code was defaulting to the main window handle instead of the currently active modal dialog.  `MessageBox` handles that and leaves the dialog as modal.  When the message box I'm using that is based on `CDialog` ends, my main window is receiving mouse/keyboard events *AND* the modal dialog still works.  In fact, I can open a second copy of the modal dialog and BOTH work.  I fixed it by not relying on the MessageBox-like behavior that `CDialog` does differently.

Comment: I only have a main thread, a winsock thread (created by the library, NOT me) and any other threads that system libraries or function might create on my behalf.  I do not call any form of `beginthread` (or anything like it).  I just wanted to know if this was a known issue with `CDialog` and apparently, it is not.  So either the class that is extending it is doing something weird I cannot find or it is an undiscovered bug.  Either way, I think I'm done here.  Thanks again for considering my question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether my answer will help you a bit.

but there is property for a Dialog box - "System Modal", which makes it System Modal Dialog.

If you set it to True, your Dialog becomes a System Modal Dialog Box.

Comment: But "System Modal" inhibits input to EVERYTHING except the message box, which is not what I want (that would be bad, in fact.)  For me the most important thing is that replacing the call to the `CDialog` based messagebox class object with a call to the actual `MessageBox` function produces the expected behavior: other modal dialogs still prevent any other input to the parent app after they are dismissed.  The class does not.